# hashtable keys that are strings not recognized

Tags: scheme, key, hashtable

Scheme's `eqv-hashtable` data structure doesn't seem to recognize keys that are strings. In the following code, I am creating a `eqv-hashtable`and creating a new datum:

```
(define state-hash (make-eqv-hashtable))
(hashtable-set! state-hash "S" (State "S" #f '() '()))
```

However, when I try to check to see if my data was stored in the hashtable, I encounter the following:

```
(hashtable-contains? state-hash "S")  ; --> #f
```

Though the `hashtable-contains?` procedure shows that key `"S"` is currently not in the hashtable, the following suggests otherwise:

```
(hashtable-keys state-hash)   ; --> #("S")
```

If I use something other than a string for the key, for example a symbol (e.g. `'S`), I don't have any problems. Any ideas why it wouldn't like a string as a key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`eqv?` returns `#t` only if its arguments refer to exactly the same object. Try this:

```
(define key "S")
(define state-hash (make-eqv-hashtable))
(hashtable-set! state-hash key (State "S" #f '() '()))
(hashtable-contains? state-hash key)
```

Comment: Ah, of course. I was forgetting that about the `eqv?` predicate. That makes sense now. Another alternative might be to use `(make-hashtable)` which I think allows one to pass a different predicate. In this case I don't want to test against `eqv?` but `equal?`. So maybe that is the way to go.

Comment: @Dylan That's right, if you don't need object _equivalence_ for the keys better stick to _equality_, it'll make things simpler. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `make-equal-hashtable`? I don't have much experience with these, but I do know that

```
(define str "S")
(eqv? str "S") => #f
(equal? str "S") => #t
```

http://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/documentation/mit-scheme-ref/Equivalence-Predicates.html#Equivalence-Predicates

Edit: Oscar has a great solution